# node async is not runned async

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am trying to use `async` to collect some additional data to my array.

for this purpose ive created the following:

```
    User_has_academy_module.findAll({
    include: [{model: Module, include: [Category, ModuleType]}],
    where: {academy_team_id: team_id, user_id: user_id}
}).then(function (modules) {
    var i = 0;
    async.map(modules, function (module,moduleCallback) {
        var act = Academy_Attempt.build();
        if(module.dataValues.is_complete == 1){
            act.findByUserTeamAndModule(module.dataValues.user_id, module.dataValues.academy_team_id, module.dataValues.module_id, function (result) {
                module.dataValues.academy_attempt = result;
                moduleCallback(null, module);

            }, function (error) {

            })
        }
    });
    onSuccess(modules);
})
```

as you can see from the above i first collect an array called `modules` that i need loop over for each of these `modules` i want to find additonal data if a value called `is_complete == 1`

once it finds a value it should set the `module.dataValues.academy_attempt = result`

Once all of the modules have been iterated it should call the callback (`onSuccess`) and return the modules.

However it runs `onSuccess` before the async call.

So my question is what am i doing wrong and how can fix it?

Comment: Just call your `onSuccess(modules)` function inside the `async.map` callback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run `onSuccess` in a completion callback to [`async.map`](https://github.com/caolan/async#map). The first callback is the iterator, runs for every mapped element; the second callback (which you currently aren't using) runs after all iterations have completed.

```
async.map(modules, function (module,moduleCallback) {
    //...
}, function(err, modules) {
    onSuccess(modules);
});
```

Currently, your code queues up the asynchronous `map` job and then runs `onSuccess` without waiting for `map` to finish (or even start).